# SSH access blocked with that iptables rules

Tags: iptables

I set these iptables rules and it blocked me ssh access (and everything else):

```
*filter

# Allow loopback
-I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow DNS
-A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

# allow outbound connection to several website
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d www.google.com -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d example.com -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -d myotherwebsite.tld -j ACCEPT

#allow inbound connection after an allowed outbound
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#allow me and my website to communicate
-A INPUT -s 2.2.2.2/32 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 1.1.1.1/32 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1/8 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -j LOG
-A OUTPUT -j LOG

#drop everything else
-P INPUT DROP

COMMIT
```

In this example my ip is 1.1.1.1, my website is 2.2.2.2 and this server is 3.3.3.3
I block all ipv6 connection (my pc is only configured in ipv4).
I'm nearly sure these rules worked in the past but it doesn't now.

Comment: These rules should allow you access from 1.1.1.1. What packets are shown in the log?

Comment: What rules are actually running? `iptables -v -L`

Comment: The last 2 lines I have: Aug 31 13:19:31 vps49442 kernel: [19024959.743671] IN= OUT=venet0 SRC=3.3.3.3 DST=1.1.1.1 LEN=104 TOS=0x10 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=15915 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=9164 WINDOW=166 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Aug 31 13:19:31 vps49442 kernel: [19024959.760049] IN= OUT=venet0 SRC=3.3.3.3 DST=1.1.1.1 LEN=40 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=182 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=52225 WINDOW=6147 RES=0x00 ACK FIN URGP=0

Comment: @cburn11 sorry I paid to get access back because I had no rescue access, so I can't check

Comment: You know that using dns names like `www.google.com` in firewall rules isn't going to work the way you expect.  The DNS names is resolve **when the rule is added**, not when the packet is forwarded. For cloud services and and sites with big CDNs, their DNS addresses are frequently changing.

Comment: @Zoredache ok noted. I using for small businesses websites... and what's the solution ?

Comment: let me guess: your OUTPUT's policy was already DROP, your (incomplete) iptables-save style syntax rules don't explicitly set OUTPUT's policy so it stays DROP, and there's no stateful rule in OUTPUT to allow replies.

Comment: So I need to add OUTPUT to my ip ?

Comment: Warning: This firewall uses stateless rules (i.e. traffic is accepted without `-m conntrack`). These can allow unexpected traffic. Switch to fully stateful firewall rules, or use a firewall generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a rule to your `OUTPUT` chain which permits packets for already-established connections. The typical rule to add to your ruleset would be:

```
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

For the SSH connection, this will serve the same purpose as the rule you described in [your earlier answer](https://serverfault.com/a/928979/131019). However, it is more generic, and will also apply to allow bidirectional flows of packets related to any other `INPUT` chain rules you might add in future, without further explicit rules in your `OUTPUT` chain.

Comment: Yes it's a better idea

Answer (score 1):

Seems that a bidirectional rule is needed, adding the following line does allow me to access my server:

```
-A OUTPUT -d 1.1.1.1/32 -j ACCEPT
```